# Deciding strategy for app subscription expiry notification in Android - (Client side or server side?)

Tags: android, node.js, alarmmanager

I need to show notification to my Android app users when their subscription for the app is expired. I figured out two ways to do this but not sure which one to choose.

1. Set daily alarm on android phone and check if the subscription date is lapsed. If it is expired, show notification to user and update the server that the app subscription is over.
2. Set daily alarm on server side (node.js) and if the subscription date is lapsed, send notification to the app using GCM. Android app will display notification to user.

Which approach is the recommended approach? Any new suggestions/strategies are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the 2nd approach, i.e. send a push to client to show the message. Main reason is, e.g. you might need to change the logic when you'll need to show it.